# SSIS: How to read, omit by matching, and write records from pipe delimited flat file in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I am a beginner in SSIS and C# programming, just got a new job and want to make a mark.  I previously created a package to convert a tab delimited flat file to a SQL Server table,  but the flat file was prepared  manually for conversion.  Now I need to automate the conversion of the pipe delimited file, which was created like a report and has several heading and sub-heading rows.  The conversion from pipe to tab delimited is not a issue for me.  However, I just can't find a way nor get any help online to understand how to read each record, determine it's content, and omit or write a record.

I put together the following SSIS C# script shown below coding from `Main ()` only, but I am getting the following error, and I don't know why I am getting it.  Can you help me out here?

> ERROR  -  (Error at Script Task1: The binary code for the script is not found.  Please open the script in the designer by clicking Edit Script button and make sure it builds successfully.  Error at Script Task 1:  There were errors during task validation.)

The script is supposed to:

1) Read each record in the pipe delimited flat file

2) check each line/record to determine if they contain the following values, and do not write records if they contain these values:

•   Spaces

•   Value - “Business Unit:” etc.

•   Value - "Empl Id |   Employee Name | Dept Id  |  Department     |  EE Home Phone  |  Emergency Contact Name  | Primary  |    Telephone  | Relationship"

•   The last value is the heading. I want to write the 1st occurrence of this heading, but do not write any other occurrences of it afterwards.

SCRIPT:

```
public void Main()
{
  string SourcePath = Dts.Variables["User::Source_Path"].Value.ToString();
  string DestinationPath = Dts.Variables["User::Destination_Path"].Value.ToString();
  string Line = string.Empty;

  try
  {
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(SourcePath))
    using (StreamWriter ds = new StreamWriter(DestinationPath))
    {
      while ((Line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
      { 
        // MessageBox.Show(Line);
        if (Line == " ")
          Console.WriteLine("Blank Line");
        else
          if (Line == "Business Unit: 069 - DEPT OF XXXX XXXXX")
            Console.WriteLine("069 Heading");
          else
            if (Line == "Business Unit: 071 - DEPT. OF YYYYY YYYYYYY")
              Console.WriteLine("071 Heading");
            else
              if (Line == "Empl Id | Employee Name | Dept Id | Department | EE Home Phone | Emergency Contact Name | Primary | Telephone | Relationship")
                Console.WriteLine("Main Heading");

        // write to destination file
        ds.WriteLine(Dts.Variables["User::Destination_Path"].Value);
      }
      // close the stream
      ds.Close();
      //string data = sr.ReadToEnd();
      //MessageBox.Show(data);
    }
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure the code is correct? Do you get any error message when you save/close the script task?

Comment: You're missing closing bracket for `Main` method

Comment: You can use the flat file source with different field and line delimiters. You don't need to convert anything. The real problem seems to be how to ignore invalid lines. You can set the error behaviour to *ignore* to ignore group headers and footers. You can specify how many header and data rows to skip. This works in most cases, except for group/page headers right after the field names

Comment: Why are you converting from pipe to tab? I don't see any point. The way I process files like this is that I import the entire row into a single column then shred that column out into multiple columns. Personally I find it much easier to debug that than trying to interactively debug a C# task inside a SSIS package.

Comment: It's my own code, so there may be incorrect portions of it.  This is what I need to determine.

Comment: I thing I may not have copied the Bracket to close Main, but I assure you the bracket is there.  Thanks for the observation.

Comment: Panagiotis, thanks for your comment.  Can you provide the suggested C# codes I could use?  Would really appreciate.

Comment: Nick, thanks for your comment.  The conversion from pipe to tab delimited is not the problem, as I could do that in SSIS.  My real problem is the C# code, which I am virtually new to.  I am not sure if my syntax are correct.  Any help will do.  How do you import an entire row into a single column then shred that column out into multiple columns?  I agree with your debugging suggestion, but please bear in mind that I am not sure how to handle most things as yet in C#, as I am just learning.  I am sure I will get better.

Comment: Why not use string split method (like a csv) but use a pipe instead of the comma as the split character.  I would also use Trim() on each field just in case there are spaces or tabs at the end of the fields.

Comment: Jdweg, thanks for your comment.  I was just checking the Syntax of how to use Length for each Line read when checking the values in each line, but couldn't find the correct syntax to do it.  I will now check if TRIM could work to ensure I am checking the correct number of characters in each IF Statement.

Comment: Your code failed to compile. Open your script task, and press "Build". And paste the errors here. If your code does not Build, don't close the Script Task code editor.

Comment: Mxix, thanks a mil for your input.  I did exactly as you mentioned, corrected the "Using System, IODisposible" option that was suggested in something I read online, and did not get the error again.  But now I am getting something that is still not the desired result.  When I run the script, I am only getting the file path printed several times, e.g.  "C:\Emergency File\PERSSS-999-DTEST.txt", instead of the content of the file itself.  How can I adjust my script to get this file written instead of the file path.

Comment: When I run my script, I am only getting the file path printed several times, e.g. "C:\Emergency File\PERSSS-999-DTEST.txt", instead of the content of the file itself. Questions:  How can I adjust my script to get this file written instead of the file path?

Answer (score 1):

The reason the file path is being printed is because you're calling `StreamWriter.WriteLine()` using the variable that holds the file path, as opposed using the text itself.  The file path will be used when initializing the `StreamWriter` and the text when the `WriteLine()` method is called.  I'd also recommend storing the text you don't want to write in string variables as done below.  As necessary, you can add additional strings that will be filtered out (i.e. the "TextToOmit" strings below).  You may need to may a couple modifications for the exact strings you want to omit, but the code below will keep on the first header and remove the subsequent strings.  You can remove the `Close()` method as it isn't necessary since this will be closed upon exiting the `using` block.  Lines with white-space are also filtered out by the `String.IndexOf` method, which returns -1 when the text is not found.  You mentioned concerns about getting a direct match, you can use the `IndexOf` method with the `StringComparision.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` parameter to match the first occurrence without case-sensitivity.  However with this approach you will want to be sure that the text you're omitting doesn't occur in any records that need to be kept, an example of this is below in initial code snippet. I'm assuming that you want to write each record on a new line, which is why the `Environment.NewLine` property is added when building the output text.

```
string sourcePath = Dts.Variables["User::Source_Path"].Value.ToString();
string destinationPath = Dts.Variables["User::Destination_Path"].Value.ToString();
string line = string.Empty;
string outputText = string.Empty;
string headerText = "YourHeaderLine";
string secondTextToOmit = "TextThatNeedsToBeOmitted";
string thirdTextToOmit = "TextThatNeedsToBeOmitted";
int headerCount = 0;
try
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sourcePath))
    {
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            //only write first occurance
            if (line == headerText && headerCount == 0)
            {
                outputText = outputText + line + Environment.NewLine;
                headerCount++;
            }
            else
             //store text in variables to do checks all in same if statement
             //IndexOf looks for while space
             if (line.IndexOf(' ') < 0 && line != headerText
                && line != secondTextToOmit && line != thirdTextToOmit)
            {
                outputText = outputText + line + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            //initialize StreamWriter using file path
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(destinationPath))
            {
                //write the string using filtered text
                writer.WriteLine(outputText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Match Without Case-Sensitivity Example:**

```
line.IndexOf(thirdTextToOmit, 0, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) < 0
```

Comment: Dear userfl89, thanks so much for you suggestions and explanations.  You answered all my questions about why you used certain statements/methods.  I incorporated the changes and tried executing the script again, but got no records written.  Do I need to add the length of the lines with the TextsToBeOmitted for get direct match of those texts?  I ultimately want to omit the these lines, so I may have to tweak the code to not write those lines.  I notice you didn't include "writer.Close();" in your code, do I need to close the writer?

Comment: @SoniaScott, I updated the post in regards to your comment, please see the Close() and StringComparision.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase sections above.

Comment: Can you post it again?  I only see a line of code with StringComparision.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase, but no Close Statement.  Question: This code is to test the value of each line to be omitted, correct?  Also, if I were to omit writing the TextsToBeOmitted lines, what is the best way to omit writing them?

Comment: I added the explanation of the Close method within the initial answer to be more concise, look for Close() in the answer.  Yes the code checks each line for the strings omit, and if the text which should be filtered out is found avoids adding these to the “outputText” string which is written out to the destination file.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the Close() statement.  However, I don't understand the explanation for "line.IndexOf(thirdTextToOmit, 0, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) < 0", and how to use it.  If you could clarify that for me, and also how to omit writing the lines that should not be written, that would be very much appreciated.  I am still testing, and will let you know my results.

Comment: "line.IndexOf(thirdTextToOmit, 0, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) < 0" would be equivalent to using LIKE '%%' in a SQL statement, to match any line that contains the string anywhere within it, otherwise it returns -1.  StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase is to remove case sensitivity.  Of course this isn't as exact and can match unintended records if they also contain the text, which is why I noted that it should be used carefully.  The second if statement omits lines with these texts, as they're not added to "outputString" and only this string is written to the file.

Comment: Hi Userfl89, your suggested IF Statement did not write any record (even though it should have worked because NOT/AND = OR), so I adjusted the statement as follows: [ if ((Line.IndexOf(' ') < 0) || (Line != headerText) || (Line != secondTextToOmit) || (Line != thirdTextToOmit)) ], but my adjustment wrote all the records, and took 2hr 49min to complete writing 21,373 records.  I did not use the suggested equivalent of LIKE'%%' because I need the exact comparison.  At this point I am just not sure why the IF logic does not work, and why it takes so long to run.  ANY OTHER SUGGESTIONS?

Comment: @SoniaScott unfortunately without seeing the actual data you're working with I can't provide much more insight.  I tested the code I posted on sample data before submitting the answer and it returned the matches I expected it to.  Without seeing your updated code it's hard to guess, but this may also be a control flow issue with the IF statements.  I'd recommend using brackets {} with these to confirm the scope and printing messages/variable values (perhaps checking the "line" string during execution) to confirm it's operating as intended.

Comment: Hi userfl89, how do I send data through this website, as an attachment, though a special link, or do I just copy the data to this box which only allows a limited amount of texts?  I could create a file of about 10 to 20 variable length records and send to you.

Comment: @SoniaScott you can edit your original question and paste sample data in it.  It doesn't need to be much, only a few records are necessary.  Make sure that it's only test data, only the format is important.

Comment: Here are a few samples:

Comment: Business Unit: 069 - XXX/XXXX XX XXXXXX XXXXXXXX

Empl Id  |  Employee Name  |  Dept Id  |  Department  |  EE Home Phone  |  Emergency Contact Name  |  Primary  |  Telephone  |  Relationship 
 
0148871 | Bonia Zlaudette | 0691111 | Administrator/Director-00 | *********** | *****NO CONTACT***** |  |  |  
1433412 | Zoone Charkee Myrea | 0691111 | Administrator/Director-00 | *********** | LLLLL RRRRRRR | Y | 646/999-6666 | Parent
1433412 | Zoone Charkee Myrea | 0691111 | Administrator/Director-00 | *********** | ZZZZZZZ DDDDDDD | N | 212/333-2222 | Oth Relat

Comment: I'm pretty sure nothing is being written due to the part of the IF statement that filters lines with spaces (line.IndexOf(' ') < 0) and it looks like there are spaces between the text and pipes (|) in your data.  Either remove this part of the IF statement or add a Derived Column that uses the TRIM function to remove leading/trailing spaces.

Comment: Hi userfl89, I removed the check for white spaces out of the IF statement, and tried executing the program again.  Some improvements.  The secondTextToOmit was in fact omitted, but all other occurrences of the headerText was not omitted. Also, I am really concerned that the run took 2hr and 36mins to process 20,937 records.  Is that normal?

Comment: @SoniaScott since the header text is looking for an exact match, it may not be finding this due to the same issue with spaces (thus not catching/omitting).  As far as the time it took to complete, that sounds a little high, although without having a prior baseline of how long a process like that typically takes to complete in your specific environment it's hard to say.

Comment: The fact that the long heading with spaces was enclosed in quotes, shouldn't C# be able to decipher the match/non-match?  I am currently looking over the Derived Column transformation that uses the TRIM function, and I will let you know if I have any questions.  However, please feel free to respond or suggest anything else that  may help.  Thanks a mil.

Comment: Correct, if heading is an exact match (with same letter-casing, spacing, etc.) then yes it would match.  Using the TRIM function should help.  Also, your still incrementing the "headerCount " int variable in the first IF statement, right?

Comment: Yes.  My new IF Statements are:  (1) For the headerCount:                   if (Line.Trim() == headerText && headerCount == 0)
   {
     outputText = outputText + Line + Environment.NewLine;
     headerCount++; }                                                                           and (2) for omitting lines:                                                                       if ((Line.Trim()== headerText) || (Line != headerText && Line != secondTextToOmit && Line != thirdTextToOmit)).   Please let me know what you think.

Comment: Make sure to use the Trim method in the second IF statement for the header text (make this Line.Trim() != headerText).  And should the check for header text be in the second IF statement twice?  If you're checking for the header with/without spaces then change the OR (||) to an AND (&&).  I'm assuming that the headerText string already has all leading/trailing spaces removed?

Comment: That's the thing I am not sure about.  I don't know if the Trim() method only removes the leading and trailing spaces only, or if it removes all spaces between the text if the spaces are more that one position.  Can you help me with that answer?

Comment: It only removes the leading/trailing spaces, all spaces between text are kept intact regardless on how much space is between text characters.

Comment: Guess what!  I GOT IT!   I used the following 2nd if statement to omit the unwanted lines:  if (Line.Trim() != "" && Line.Trim() != headerText && Line != headerText && Line != secondTextToOmit && Line != thirdTextToOmit).  THANK YOU SO MUCH. Now I am going to run it with the file containing 20,937 records and see how long it's going to take.  I do plan to take a C# course to sharpen my beginner's skills.   I will let you know how the run with 20,937 records work.

Comment: Good to hear, great job.  If you could mark my answer as accepted I would appreciate it.  However you did a lot of trouble-shooting on this too so if you want to leave the post the way it is that works too.  Good job again on getting this sorted out.

Comment: I got the logic, but the runtime takes forever.  It took an Elapsed time of: 09hrs:35mins:34sec to rewrite 20,958 records overnight, and I have two files to process this way in each run.  Is there a faster way to read, match, and write these records.  There is a File.Copy method.  Is that a faster way to write a file, and if so, wouldn't I still need to read the file to match the values in each record?

Comment: Yes there are more efficient ways to do this.  A couple options would be to use a Flat File Connection Manager instead, then use a Conditional Split to discard non-matching rows.  If you would prefer to use a script task, another method would to only initially pull in the qualifying records, possibly using LINQ to perform filtering.

Comment: Thanks userfl89.   Bear in mind that my flat file is pipe delimited, the 4th row may have the HeaderText to keep, the 1st to 3rd rows may have either white spaces or RowToBeOmitted, and the other rows have good data or HeaderTextToBeOmitted or RowToBeOmitted.   I added a flat file connection manager, defined a pipe delimiter, but that only shows one column, i.e. Column0, instead of several columns.  Afterwards, I added a Conditional Split Transformation, and tried to configure the FindString function, but not sure how to do it.  Any suggestions?  If what I said is not clear please let me know.

Comment: I guess what I should ask is, what function should I use in the Conditional Split Transformation to prevent the writing of RowsToBeOmitted, and how do I treat the data now housed in Column 0 instead of 9 columns, since I did not select "Column names in the first data row" box, because the 1st row may not contain the HeaderText.

Comment: For something like this importing the flat file as a single column then using a script component (different from a script task) to apply logic would probably be the best option.  The conditional split could either be used afterwards or the incoming data could be filtering accordingly in the prior tasks, and which choice is made depends on several factors.  Unfortunately, that's out of the scope of these comments, and I really can't provide much more here that will be too helpful from smaller comments such as these.

Comment: I really appreciated your help.  Sorry about my limited knowledge so far, but you really helped me a lot.  I will continue to research my options, and possibly start a new tread asking about SSIS.  Thanks again.

Comment: No problem at all, glad I could help.  I'm sure as you continue working with SSIS these things will come much easier in the future.

Comment: I am sure it will.  Just wanted to get this project working efficiently, and I thought this C# script could work, but I realize I have to research another way to read the file.  I might also look into using a VB script.  Again, thank you.